# Corrupted or Blank file is getting by email through Web app - Google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, file-upload, large-files, multiple-file-upload

**Question**

Below google script running fine but the file uploaded send via email is corrupted or blank while getting through  email.. Attached filename, content type are same as uploaded... but getting file cannot be opened.. text files are fine... Could any one can help in this regard.

Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function processForm(formObject) {
  var myFile = formObject.myFile;

  var FileBytes = myFile.getBytes();
  var FileType = myFile.getContentType();
  var FileName = myFile.getName();
  var FileToSend = {
    fileName: FileName,
    content: FileBytes,
    mimeType: FileType
  };
  // Logger.log(FileType);

  var FileBytes2 = [100, 97, 121, 32, 108, 97, 32, 110, 111, 105, 32, 100, 117, 110, 103, 32, 98, 101, 110, 32, 116, 114, 111, 110, 103];
  var FileToSend2 = {
    fileName: 'test222.txt',
    content: FileBytes2,
    mimeType: 'text/plain'
  };
  var FileToSend3 = {
    fileName: 'test333.txt',
    content: 'noi dung ben trong',
    mimeType: 'text/plain'
  };

  GmailApp.sendEmail('email@domain', '6 Attachment example', '6 Please see the attached file.', {
    attachments: [FileToSend, FileToSend2, FileToSend3],
    name: '6 Automatic Emailer Script'
  });

  return FileName;
}
```

*index.html*

```
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // Prevent forms from submitting.
    function preventFormSubmit() {
      var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
      for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
        forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();
        });
      }
    }
    window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);

    function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateUrl).processForm(formObject);
    }

    function updateUrl(filename) {
      var div = document.getElementById('output');
      div.innerHTML = filename;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>



  <form action="#" id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="file-field input-field">
      <div class="btn">
        <span>File</span>
        <input name="myFile" type="file" multiple>
      </div>
      <div class="file-path-wrapper">
        <input class="file-path validate" type="text" placeholder="Upload one or more files">
       </div>
    </div>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
<div id="output"></div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your issue, in the `handleFormSubmit` function, I took an array buffer and transformed it into a string containing the file data and pass it to your `processForm` function, in order for that logic to be handled in the frontend instead of the backend, [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) is a little picky with the values you can pass as arguments. Therefore, your `handleFormSubmit` function will look like this now:

```js
 const handleFormSubmit = async (formObject) => {
      // Get all the file data
      let file = formObject.myFile.files[0];
      // Get binary content, we have to wait because it returns a promise 
      let fileBuffer = await file.arrayBuffer();
      // Get the file content as binary and then pass it to string 
      const data = (new Uint8Array(fileBuffer)).toString();
      // Pass the file meta data and the content 
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateUrl).processForm(file.name, file.type, data);
}
```

As for the backend function `processForm` , you will need to transform the `data` string into a binary data array again, that's why I use `JSON.parse("[" + data + "]")`. Now, your `processForm` will look like this:

```
function processForm(name, type, data) {
  var fileToSend = {
    fileName: name,
    // Convert the string to a Binary data array
    content: JSON.parse("[" + data + "]"), 
    mimeType: type
  };
  GmailApp.sendEmail('email@domain', '6 Attachment example', '6 Please see the attached file.', {
    attachments: [fileToSend],
    name: '6 Automatic Emailer Script'
  });
  return "this file " + name + " has just been sent to your email";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @LeCat, this helped me so much and saved me a headache, you're a beautiful genius! I'd up-vote you if I could.

Comment: I'm really glad my answer helped you @AndresDuarte :D