# Upload file to my google drive with Google Apps Script (NO FORM IN GOOGLE)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-apps-script

so basically the task is quite simple, but I didn't find any workable solution for my problem. I have a huge upload script on my website (at the moment localhost), but lets reduce all the complexity to the only neccessary.

**So I just want to upload a single file to Google Drive with Google App Script and receive the URL of it to save it in a var, to work with that information on a later point in my function.**

Now the problem is I already have the form on my website, I dont want the form inside script.google.com as extra html, I want to transfer my user input to Google App Script, then upload it to google drive and return the url back to my website where I can save it into a var.

My problem now is, I cant put all the stuff together.

**This is the form on my website (simplified):**

```
<form name="myForm" method="post">
            <!-- <form name="first-form"> -->

  <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="myName">
  <input type="file" name="myFile" id="myFile">
  <button onclick="UploadFile()" type="submit">submit</button>

</form>
```

So how can I upload my informations inside google drive and get back a result? How can I push the data in Google App Script without using iFrame or anything else?

THANK YOU!

**** Working example if html is in scripts.google.com ****

gs

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('forms.html').setTitle("Google File Upload by CTRLQ.org");
}


function uploadFileToGoogleDrive(data, file, name, email) {
  
  try {
    
    var dropbox = "Received Files";
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);
    
    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }
    
    /* Credit: www.labnol.org/awesome */
    
    var contentType = data.substring(5,data.indexOf(';')),
        bytes = Utilities.base64Decode(data.substr(data.indexOf('base64,')+7)),
        blob = Utilities.newBlob(bytes, contentType, file),
        file = folder.createFolder([name, email].join(" ")).createFile(blob);
    
    return "OK";
    
  } catch (f) {
    return f.toString();
  }
  
}
```

html in apps.googlescript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_blank">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Google File Upload by CTRLQ.org</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/css/materialize.min.css">
    <style>
      .disclaimer{width: 480px; color:#646464;margin:20px auto;padding:0 16px;text-align:center;font:400 12px Roboto,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif}.disclaimer a{color:#009688}#credit{display:none}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- Written by Amit Agarwal amit@labnol.org --> 

    <form class="main" id="form" novalidate="novalidate" style="max-width: 480px;margin: 40px auto;">
      <div id="forminner">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col s12">
            <h5 class="center-align teal-text">Upload Files to my Google Drive</h5>
            <p class="disclaimer">This <a href="http://www.labnol.org/internet/file-upload-google-forms/29170/">File Upload Form</a> (<a href="https://youtu.be/C_YBBupebvE">tutorial</a>) is powered by <a href="https://ctrlq.org/code/19747-google-forms-upload-files" target="_blank">Google Scripts</a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="name" type="text" name="Name" class="validate" required="" aria-required="true">
            <label for="name">Name</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input id="email" type="email" name="Email" class="validate" required="" aria-required="true">
            <label for="email">Email Address</label>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="file-field input-field col s12">
            <div class="btn">
              <span>File</span>
              <input id="files" type="file">
            </div>
            <div class="file-path-wrapper">
              <input class="file-path validate" type="text" placeholder="Select a file on your computer">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s6">
            <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn submit-btn" type="submit" onclick="submitForm(); return false;">Submit</button>
          </div>   
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12" id = "progress">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="success" style="display:none">
        <h5 class="left-align teal-text">File Uploaded</h5>
        <p>Your file has been successfully uploaded.</p>
        <p>The <a href="http://www.labnol.org/internet/file-upload-google-forms/29170/">pro version</a> (see <a href="">demo form</a>) includes a visual drag-n-drop form builder, CAPTCHAs, the form responses are saved in a Google Spreadsheet and respondents can upload multiple files of any size.</p>    
        <p class="center-align"><a  class="btn btn-large" href="https://gum.co/GA14?wanted=true" target="_blank">Upgrade to Pro</a></p>
      </div>
    </form>

    <div class="fixed-action-btn horizontal" style="bottom: 45px; right: 24px;">
      <a class="btn-floating btn-large red">
        <i class="large material-icons">menu</i>
      </a>
      <ul>
        <li><a class="btn-floating red"  href="https://gum.co/GA14" target="_blank" title="Buy License - File Upload Form"><i class="material-icons">monetization_on</i></a></li>
        <li><a class="btn-floating blue"  href="https://youtu.be/C_YBBupebvE" target="_blank" title="Video Tutorial"><i class="material-icons">video_library</i></a></li>
        <li><a class="btn-floating green" href="http://www.labnol.org/internet/file-upload-google-forms/29170/" target="_blank" title="How to Create File Upload Forms"><i class="material-icons">help</i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.5/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://gumroad.com/js/gumroad.js"></script>

    <script>

      var file, 
          reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onloadend = function(e) {
        if (e.target.error != null) {
          showError("File " + file.name + " could not be read.");
          return;
        } else {
          google.script.run
            .withSuccessHandler(showSuccess)
            .uploadFileToGoogleDrive(e.target.result, file.name, $('input#name').val(), $('input#email').val());
        }
      };

      function showSuccess(e) {
        if (e === "OK") { 
          $('#forminner').hide();
          $('#success').show();
        } else {
          showError(e);
        }
      }

      function submitForm() {

        var files = $('#files')[0].files;

        if (files.length === 0) {
          showError("Please select a file to upload");
          return;
        }

        file = files[0];

        if (file.size > 1024 * 1024 * 5) {
          showError("The file size should be < 5 MB. Please <a href='http://www.labnol.org/internet/file-upload-google-forms/29170/' target='_blank'>upgrade to premium</a> for receiving larger files in Google Drive");
          return;
        }

        showMessage("Uploading file..");

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);

      }

      function showError(e) {
        $('#progress').addClass('red-text').html(e);
      }

      function showMessage(e) {
        $('#progress').removeClass('red-text').html(e);
      }


    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

As reccomended Im going to describe the process here.

So we are on the website: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) , there is a form with text input field and file field. Lets say we put in an image and call it example. Now if we press submit, I want to upload the image to google drive without any oAuth (Thats why we need to use google app script here) and name it to what we typed in the textfield. When the upload is done, I want the url of the image of google drive to be returned back to the website, so the form can continue working with the information. I want to save the returned url in a var then, to later on save it in a database. Thats why I need the result back to my website.

So scheme looks like the following:

Enter informations to form on website -> Redirected to google app script: take informations of website form field and upload file to google drive and name it like text input entry -> taking url of google drive as final result -> redirecting final url result back to website -> saving url result in var and continuing doing stuff from function on website -> at the end saving the informations from var to a database -> finish

------------------------------------------------ EDIT: ------------------

Thanks to @Tanaike Im a lot closer to the goal of my challenge here, so in order to see where I got stuck, I'm replicating my issue now:

I took the form with the script from your example:

```
<form id="form">
  <input name="file" id="uploadfile" type="file">
  <input name="filename" id="filename" type="text">
  <input id="submit" type="submit">
</form>
<script>
const form = document.getElementById('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const file = form.file.files[0];
  const fr = new FileReader();
  fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  fr.onload = f => {
    
    const url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec";  // <--- Please set the URL of Web Apps.
    
    const qs = new URLSearchParams({filename: form.filename.value || file.name, mimeType: file.type});
    fetch(`${url}?${qs}`, {method: "POST", body: JSON.stringify([...new Int8Array(f.target.result)])})
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(e => console.log(e))  // <--- You can retrieve the returned value here.
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
});
</script>
```

and for google script:

```
function doPost(e) {
  // const folderId = "###";  // Folder ID which is used for putting the file, if you need.

  const blob = Utilities.newBlob(JSON.parse(e.postData.contents), e.parameter.mimeType, e.parameter.filename);
  const file = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId || "root").createFile(blob);
  const responseObj = {filename: file.getName(), fileId: file.getId(), fileUrl: file.getUrl()};
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(responseObj)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

Now when i tried to upload something I had following error: CORS Policy not able to fetch. So I changed this part to the following and added mode no cors:

```
const qs = new URLSearchParams({filename: form.filename.value || file.name, mimeType: file.type});
        fetch(`${url}?${qs}`, {method: "POST", mode: "no-cors", body: JSON.stringify([...new Int8Array(f.target.result)])})
```

This worked. Second try uploading the file caused in the following error:
it says:  `syntax error: unexpected end of input`

So I changed this line and removed the brackets from res.json

```
JSON.stringify([...new Int8Array(f.target.result)])})
        .then(res => res.json)
```

third try to upload the file actually worked with the following console result:

```
ƒ json() { [native code] }
```

But there is no file uploaded in google drive. Im missing something somewhere. Maybe we should create a folder and place the files in there.

Oh and another information: when i run doPost function in google app sript it says:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'postData' of undefined (line 13
```

EDIT2 -----------------------------------------

I added https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=###fileId### to your code and everything works fine. The file is getting uploaded.

Lets say we upload the file test.mp3 and we call it testdata.
This is what we recieve:

```
{
  "filename": "testdata",
  "fileId": "###some id##",
  "fileUrl": "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=###fileId###"
}
```

Now when I open the file url, the browser downloads file but its called: testdata, not testdata.mp3. The filetyp ending is missing.

Second task: If you click the link, I want to open the file in browser, when its mp3 file for example i want that you can play the sound in webview, like it is here: https://files.freemusicarchive.org/storage-freemusicarchive-org/music/Creative_Commons/Dead_Combo/CC_Affiliates_Mixtape_1/Dead_Combo_-_01_-_Povo_Que_Cas_Descalo.mp3

I hope you can guide me!

Comment: Check it out: https://developers.google.com/picker/docs/

Comment: Thank you for the link, as far as I know, you neet the oAuth authentification, I need a public upload, so this approach doesnt work for me.

Comment: Try a.web app and I frame it into you website

Comment: how would this look like? I need a result to my website then to save it in a var, is it possible with an iframe?

Comment: This is a little hard to follow. Can you lay out a step-by-step process of the workflow? `Submit form > data gets posted to x > redirect to y` etc?

Comment: I edited my answear with a description

Comment: Do you have a `doPost()` method for posting the file to the Web App?

Comment: not yet, tbh, I dont have any idea how to get it work. Would be great if you can make and show an example so I can learn from it. So if I understood what youre saying, we need a doPost function to get the form information to the google app script. What do I have to change to the form on my website to get the informations to google app script via doPost and how to get the url as answer back to it?

Comment: [Upload File Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60643220/7215091)

Comment: @Marcel Dz I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Can I confirm whether my understanding of your goal is correct? Your web site is not related to Google account. It's independent. Your web site has a form for uploading a file. When users submit the form, you want to upload the file to your Google Drive, and want to return the URL of the uploaded file on Google Drive. Is my understanding correct? If my understanding is correct, in this case, the file is not shared. So users cannot directly retrieve the uploaded file. How about this?

Comment: @Tanaike Yes your understanding is completely correct. Yes they can not directly retrieve the uploaded file, I just need it to save it in a variable and write it in a database. Could your provide an example or even better a solution?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot image your goal from `I just need it to save it in a variable and write it in a database.`. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: i need to save the final link in the database to later on display it in an app

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I understood that `database` is prepared by you. So I proposed a sample script for uploading a file to Google Drive as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- Your web site is not related to Google account. It's independent.
- Your web site has a form for uploading a file.
- When users submit the form, you want to upload the file to your Google Drive without the authorization, and want to return the URL of the uploaded file on Google Drive.
- About "Database", this is your database. You will put the retrieved URL of the file to "Database" at the client side.

In this case, I think that your goal can be achieved using the Web Apps created by Google Apps Script.

### Usage:

Please do the following flow.

#### 1. Create new project of Google Apps Script.

Sample script of Web Apps is a Google Apps Script. So please create a project of Google Apps Script.

If you want to directly create it, please access to https://script.new/. In this case, if you are not logged in Google, the log in screen is opened. So please log in to Google. By this, the script editor of Google Apps Script is opened.

#### 2. Prepare script.

Please copy and paste the following script (Google Apps Script) to the script editor. This script is for the Web Apps.

##### Server side: Google Apps Script

Please set the folder ID that you want to put the file.

```
function doPost(e) {
  const folderId = "root";  // Or Folder ID which is used for putting the file instead of "root", if you need.

  const blob = Utilities.newBlob(JSON.parse(e.postData.contents), e.parameter.mimeType, e.parameter.filename);
  const file = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId).createFile(blob);
  const responseObj = {filename: file.getName(), fileId: file.getId(), fileUrl: file.getUrl()};
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(responseObj)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

#### 3. Deploy Web Apps.

1. On the script editor, Open a dialog box by "Publish" -> "Deploy as web app".
2. Select **"Me"** for **"Execute the app as:"**.

   - By this, the script is run as the owner.
3. Select **"Anyone, even anonymous"** for **"Who has access to the app:"**.
4. Click "Deploy" button as new "Project version".
5. Automatically open a dialog box of "Authorization required".

   1. Click "Review Permissions".
   2. Select own account.
   3. Click "Advanced" at "This app isn't verified".
   4. Click "Go to ### project name ###(unsafe)"
   5. Click "Allow" button.
6. Click "OK".
7. Copy the URL of Web Apps. It's like `https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec`.

   - **When you modified the Google Apps Script, please redeploy as new version. By this, the modified script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.**

#### 4. Upload a file from client side to server side.

##### Client side: HTML & Javascript

Please set the URL of your Web Apps to the following script.

```html
<form id="form">
  <input name="file" id="uploadfile" type="file">
  <input name="filename" id="filename" type="text">
  <input id="submit" type="submit">
</form>
<script>
const form = document.getElementById('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const file = form.file.files[0];
  const fr = new FileReader();
  fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  fr.onload = f => {
    
    const url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec";  // <--- Please set the URL of Web Apps.
    
    const qs = new URLSearchParams({filename: form.filename.value || file.name, mimeType: file.type});
    fetch(`${url}?${qs}`, {method: "POST", body: JSON.stringify([...new Int8Array(f.target.result)])})
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(e => console.log(e))  // <--- You can retrieve the returned value here.
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
});
</script>
```

- At the client side, when you selected a file from your local PC and push the button, the file is uploaded to your Google Drive by retrieving the data at the Web Apps (server side).

##### Result:

When above script is run, the following value is returned. From this, you can retrieve the URL of the file.

```
{
  "filename": "### inputted filename ###",
  "fileId": "###",
  "fileUrl": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/###/view?usp=drivesdk"
}
```

### Note:

- **When you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- In above script, the maximum file size is 50 MB. Because in the current stage, the maximum blob size is 50 MB at Google Apps Script.

### References:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Taking advantage of Web Apps with Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tanaikech/taking-advantage-of-Web-Apps-with-google-apps-script)

Comment: This is amazing!! thousand thanks for this informative step by step guide! I'll try it when im done with work, but what I saw as far by fast scrolling, there are alot of relevant informations you provided me and it seems like THIS is the perfect solution for my challenge. I just can again say, THOUSANDS OF THANKS TO YOU!!

Comment: Good morning, I wanted you to give you some feedback. So first of all i got cors policy error but I figured it out by adding mode: 'no-cors' to the line after fetch post. Now at the moment im getting a syntax error in this line: .then(res => res.json()), it says unexpected end of input

Comment: @Marcel Dz Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. Because when I tested it, I could confirm that no error occurs. So I proposed above it. I deeply apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about your situation and correctly replicate your situation, can you provide the detail information for replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your issue? If you can do it, please add the detail flow in your question.

Comment: Thank you for fast repliying, i just got it by changing .then(res => res.json() to .then( res=> res.json) without the brackets it works. Now when I upload a file, Im receiving something like this: ƒ json() { [native code] } but the file isnt uploaded yet in drive

Comment: @Marcel Dz Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. Because when I tested it, I could confirm that no error occurs. So I proposed above it. I deeply apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about your situation and correctly replicate your situation, can you provide the detail information for replicating your current issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your issue? If you can do it, please add the detail flow in your question.

Comment: I edited my question and replicated everything. Hopefully you can provide me the missing part for the solution! THANKS!

Comment: @Marcel Dz Thank you for replying and adding the information. From your updated question, I would like to confirm about your current script. About `// const folderId = "###";`, when you modified to `const folderId = "root";` or `const folderId = "###FolderId###";` and test it again, what result will you get? Because I had supposed that `//` of `// const folderId = "###";` is removed. I apologize for this. And when you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to Web Apps. Please be careful this.

Comment: @Marcel Dz In that case, please use `.then(res => res.json()).then(e => console.log(e))` at the client side.

Comment: @Marcel Dz And, in order to avoid the confusion, also I updated my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219794/discussion-between-marcel-dz-and-tanaike).

Comment: I finally got it working! I configured server with CORS and now your script works. How to retrieve the downloadurl not view url of the file? And second question, If i upload a .mp3 file it gets uploaded, it says: [Violation] 'load' handler took 1343ms should i do something here?

Comment: @Marcel Dz Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Unfortunately, I cannot still replicate your situation. I apologize for this. About the URL of download, I think that is `webContentLink`. In this case, it can be retrieved by Drive API. But the format of URL is constant. So you can create it using the file ID like `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=###fileId###`. I think that this is the easy way.

Comment: ok where do I have to change what? I dont know anything of this drive api..

Comment: @Marcel Dz I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I had proposed the method without using the Drive API. It's `https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=###fileId###` using the file ID.

Comment: @Marcel Dz When the response value is retrieved, the file ID is included. So you can create the URL using the file ID. In this case, you can modify the script of server side or the client side.

Comment: @Marcel Dz When you want to modify the server side, please modify `fileUrl: file.getUrl()` to `fileUrl: "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + file.getId()`. When you want to modify the client side, please modify `.then(e => console.log(e))` to `.then(e => console.log("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + e.fileId))`.

Comment: perfect, i did it with .then(e => console.log(e)) to .then(e => console.log("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + e.fileId))

Comment: When I download it, the filetype is missing, for example .mp3. And how can I have the mode where you can play for example the mp3 in browser? Is it also export=download&id or is it different mode?

Comment: @Marcel Dz Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new issue, I would like to support you. But unfortunately, I cannot understand about `When I download it, the filetype is missing, for example .mp3. And how can I have the mode where you can play for example the mp3 in browser? Is it also export=download&id or is it different mode?`. And this is not shown in your initial question. So can you post it as new question by including more information? By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad.

Comment: i editet my question down below, hopefully you can help me!

Comment: @Marcel Dz Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I would like to support you. But the issue of your comment is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question by including the detail information? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of your new question. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad.

Comment: yes of course, I made a question for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63415373/how-to-retrieve-absolute-link-of-google-drive-file-from-return-statement Hopefully you can solve my new issue! THANKS!

Comment: @Marcel Dz Thank you for your response. I will check it.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of useful tips in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63391363/1585523 answer! Thank you for sharing. Instead of POSTing the file, we could also use

**On the client: index.html**

```js
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileName => {}).withFailureHandler(error => {}).saveInDrive(fileAsByteArray);
```

**On the server: Code.gs**

```js
function saveInDrive(f) {
  const blob = Utilities.newBlob(f, "image/jpeg", "some-name");
  const file = DriveApp.getFolderById("root").createFile(blob);
  return file.getName()
}
```

You can even exchange complicated types like JS objects with binary info as values as well in this approach.

Comment: could you elaborate on how fileAsByteArray is defined?

Comment: Depends on how you are getting the original file. On source can be fetch API: e.g. `const fileAsByteArray = new File([Uint8Array.from(await fetchResp)], "myfile.bin")`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array/Uint8Array takes inp in many ways

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that adding

> mode: 'no-cors'

is right way because then this mode will block app from reading response(cors policies), which by the way comes not from response to initial request but from [second redirected GET request](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/content#redirects)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31897730)