# How to retrieve absolute link of google drive file from return statement?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I have a html form and Im uploading a media file to google drive and return the file.
This is my code:

```
<form id="form">
  <input name="file" id="uploadfile" type="file">
  <input name="filename" id="filename" type="text">
  <input id="submit" type="submit">
</form>
<script>
const form = document.getElementById('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const file = form.file.files[0];
  const fr = new FileReader();
  fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  fr.onload = f => {
    
    const url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec";  // <--- Please set the URL of Web Apps.
    
    const qs = new URLSearchParams({filename: form.filename.value || file.name, mimeType: file.type});
    fetch(`${url}?${qs}`, {method: "POST", body: JSON.stringify([...new Int8Array(f.target.result)])})
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(e => console.log("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + e.fileId))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
});
</script>
```

Now when I upload example.mp3 and type in textinput field stackoverflow, im receiving a downloadlink. I expect that the file which will get downloaded is stackoverflow.mp3 then, but its only stackoverflow, the filetype ending is missing. Does anybody see what im missing there?

Anyways, what I want to return is the final, or directlink of the file in google drive. (I dont know the word for it, sorry for my bad english)

If you click the link, I want to open the file in browser, I want that you can play the sound in webview, like it is here: https://files.freemusicarchive.org/storage-freemusicarchive-org/music/Creative_Commons/Dead_Combo/CC_Affiliates_Mixtape_1/Dead_Combo_-_01_-_Povo_Que_Cas_Descalo.mp3

how to change my javascript to recieve this kind of link?

————— EDIT ———

One stackoverflow User described how to get the link I need. How to put this steps in the script?

I was trying to accomplish this inside the SSML audio tag for Actions on Google. None of the above steps seemed to work. I finally found a solution.

1. Get the file ID from the sharing link https://drive.google.com/file/d/your_file_id/view?usp=sharing
2. Construct the direct link http://docs.google.com/uc?export=open&id=your_file_id
3. Paste the direct link into a web browser and hit enter
4. Copy the resulting URL after you have been redirected by your browser Note: This will be a much longer URL that looks something like this: https://doc-XX-XX-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/000000000000000/0000000000000000000000/*/your_file_id?e=open

Using this final URL is the only way I could get my uploaded sound files to work with Actions on Google.

Comment: Does you file is played if you open it from Google Drive web UI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the file type is kept on the Google Drive. But when the file is downloaded, I thought that the file type might be not known because of no extension. So how about adding the extension when the file is uploaded?

When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
fr.onload = f => {
  
  const url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec";  // <--- Please set the URL of Web Apps.
  
  const qs = new URLSearchParams({filename: form.filename.value || file.name, mimeType: file.type});
  fetch(`${url}?${qs}`, {method: "POST", body: JSON.stringify([...new Int8Array(f.target.result)])})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(e => console.log("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + e.fileId))
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

To:

```
fr.onload = f => {
  // I added below script.
  let newName = form.filename.value;
  const orgName = file.name;
  if (orgName.includes(".")) {
    const orgExt = orgName.split(".").pop();
    if (orgExt != newName.split(".").pop()) {
      newName = newName ? `${newName}.${orgExt}` : orgName;
    }
  }
  
  const url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec";
  
  const qs = new URLSearchParams({filename: newName, mimeType: file.type});  // Modified
  fetch(`${url}?${qs}`, {method: "POST", body: JSON.stringify([...new Int8Array(f.target.result)])})
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(e => console.log(e.fileUrl))  // <--- You can retrieve the returned value here.
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Comment: check my question, I have found what I exactly need, one stackoverflow user described how he gets the final link. THIS is the link I need. How to modify the script to receive this link? I’m super sorry that I didn’t find it earlier, can you show me how to modify the script for this link? THANK YOU MAN!

Comment: @Marcel Dz Thank you for replying. I'm glad your question was resolved. About your new question, I would like to support you. But I cannot understand about it. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. And I think that your additional question is different from your initial question. So I would like to recommend to post it as new question. How about this? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad.

Comment: yes sir! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63424432/google-drive-api-how-to-get-the-absolut-link-final This is the question, hopefully you can help me buddy!

Comment: @Marcel Dz Thank you for your response. I will check it.