# Google drive api: How to get the absolut link (final) as returnment From my script

Tags: javascript, url, google-apps-script, google-drive-api, actions-on-google

I need the absolute google drive api link as result from my script but I don’t know how.

This is my script:

I have a html form and Im uploading a media file to google drive and return the file.
This is my code:

```
<form id="form">
  <input name="file" id="uploadfile" type="file">
  <input name="filename" id="filename" type="text">
  <input id="submit" type="submit">
</form>
<script>
const form = document.getElementById('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const file = form.file.files[0];
  const fr = new FileReader();
  fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  fr.onload = f => {
    
    const url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec";  // <--- Please set the URL of Web Apps.
    
    const qs = new URLSearchParams({filename: form.filename.value || file.name, mimeType: file.type});
    fetch(`${url}?${qs}`, {method: "POST", body: JSON.stringify([...new Int8Array(f.target.result)])})
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(e => console.log("https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + e.fileId))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
});
</script>
```

This is my server script

```
function doPost(e) {
  const folderId = "root";  // Folder ID which is used for putting the file, if you need.

  const blob = Utilities.newBlob(JSON.parse(e.postData.contents), e.parameter.mimeType, e.parameter.filename);
  const file = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId || "root").createFile(blob);
  const responseObj = {filename: file.getName(), fileId: file.getId(), fileUrl: file.getUrl()};
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(responseObj)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

One stackoverflow User described how to get the link I need. How to put this steps in the script?

1. Get the file ID from the sharing link https://drive.google.com/file/d/your_file_id/view?usp=sharing
2. Construct the direct link http://docs.google.com/uc?export=open&id=your_file_id
3. Paste the direct link into a web browser and hit enter
4. Copy the resulting URL after you have been redirected by your browser Note: This will be a much longer URL that looks something like this: https://doc-XX-XX-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/000000000000000/0000000000000000000000/*/your_file_id?e=open

Using this final URL is the only way I could get my uploaded sound files to work with Actions on Google.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219894/discussion-on-question-by-marcel-dz-google-drive-api-how-to-get-the-absolut-lin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting the fileUrl, use [`Urlfetch`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params) to fetch the resource. If it is redirected, you'll [get status code](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/http-response#getresponsecode) [`302`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/302) with the redirected url in [`Location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location) header. Authorization can be handled with [`ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#getOAuthToken()), if needed.

```
const url = `https://docs.google.com/uc?export=open&id=${file.getId()}`;
const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,{
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}`
  },
  followRedirects: false
});
const statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
if (String(statusCode)[0] === "3") console.log(response.getAllHeaders()['Location'])
else console.log("No redirect")
```

Comment: thank your for your solution! Unfortunately i'm not good in javascript I still have to learn alot and im not able to integrate your solution into my serverside script. Can you insert it correctly, so I can learn from it?

Comment: @MarcelDz Instead, Could you tell me where you're having problem? I haven't tested this and you might have to debug. I need you to learn js enough to debug or at least be clear with error messages

Comment: yes, first of all I tried to implement it in my javascript code, but I noticed that all the functions are only available serverside on my doPost function. Now in the doPost function I have basically no idea how to receive the final link as answer to clientside

Comment: 1.You `return` it just like you're returning `responseObj` now. 2. Are you able to view the required links in logs? 3.Please read all the links in my question

Comment: im getting cors policy error. Im testing it on a xamp server, I already created a .htaccess file with Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost:50000/", but it gives me the No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. error

Comment: @Tanaike did you find a solution? For no confusion I made an extra question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63434728/how-to-stream-music-in-my-app-from-google-drive-link-and-make-the-link-accessibl

Comment: @Marcel Dz I saw it. I noticed that an answer has already been posted. In this case, I would like to respect the existing answer. I think that it will resolve your issue.