# How to stream music in my app from Google Drive link and make the link accessible?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

On a website users are able to upload music. This music is getting uploaded in my google drive account. After that the following link format is written into the database:

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?id=ID_GOES_HERE
```

Now when you access the link it changes in something like this:

```
https://doc-14-8s-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/m4p0h6h3bpkoufgbajruvng9n4f51clu/fnjf7ftnl18svtcblses77hapi91jpe5/1597565925000/10139445714759083419/10139445714759083419/1mLu_myEgts9eaoWv6S9nxu8n4qfZM0Rr?authuser=0
```

The long link is the link in the database which is used for the app to play the music, but I dont have permission to open it there anymore. How can I make the last and long link accessible? Is there any way to make this long link public?

Thank you!

```
    <form id="form">
  <input name="file" id="uploadfile" type="file">
  <input name="filename" id="filename" type="text">
  <input id="submit" type="submit">
</form>
<script>
const form = document.getElementById('form');
form.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const file = form.file.files[0];
  const fr = new FileReader();
  fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  fr.onload = f => {
    
    const url =   "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec";  // <---    Please set the URL of Web Apps.

    const qs = new URLSearchParams({filename:    form.filename.value || file.name, mimeType: file.type});
fetch(`${url}?${qs}`, {method: "POST", body: JSON.stringify([...new Int8Array(f.target.result)])})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(e => console.log("https://drive.google.com/uc?   export=download&id=" + e.fileId))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
});
</script>
```

This is the google app script

```
function doPost(e) {
  const folderId = "root";  // Folder ID which is used for   putting the file, if you need.

  const blob =   Utilities.newBlob(JSON.parse(e.postData.contents),   e.parameter.mimeType, e.parameter.filename);
  const file = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId ||  "root").createFile(blob);
  const responseObj = {filename: file.getName(), fileId:  file.getId(), fileUrl: file.getUrl()};
  return   ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(responseObj  )).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

------- EDIT -------

I tried the given solution:

sadly it doesnt work as expected.. Im getting the following link:

```
https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1Tnh8UgAzFKrp6e-8QCl21v16L3yVCqso
```

now when I take the id from it and insert it here:

```
http://docs.google.com/uc?export=open&id=your_file_id
```

the result of it is a really long link which is the link i need. This one is still not accessible if im in private browser mode for example, it forces me to login which I dont want. It should be accessible with link like in your solution. This is the link:

```
https://doc-08-8s-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/m4p0h6h3bpkoufgbajruvng9n4f51clu/cgag5dus6c18p9hc1hv0362urudm2g6t/1597730475000/10139445714759083419/10139445714759083419/1Tnh8UgAzFKrp6e-8QCl21v16L3yVCqso?e=open&authuser=0
```

how to make this link accessible?

It seems like this link has the permissions you have set http://docs.google.com/uc?export=open&id=your_file_id but if you copy the long link, this one doesnt provide the permission settings, it still blocks.

Comment: I don’t want to make it to complicate for my problem in the Description, the upload form on my website is only accessible with a valid account on the website. It’s not completely accessible from outside

Comment: Show us the code how you are uploading to drive

Comment: @Viney I posted the code. Is there a way to receive this long link with permission?

Comment: Looks like you are using google app script so you need to look there how to set the permission of uploaded files to public

Comment: I added the app script but I don’t know how to set the permission can you modify my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After creating your file you need to give it a proper [access level](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/access) which determines who can access it and also a [permission level](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/permission) which determines what they can do with that file (read/write/delete)

For you use case it should be publicly accessible with a link and readonly. So this is how you can do in the app script

```
const file = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId ||  "root").createFile(blob);
file.setSharing(DriveApp.Access.ANYONE_WITH_LINK, DriveApp.Permission.VIEW); // <-- add this
```

Comment: Are you trying to directly link to the CDN? the link https://doc-08-8s-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/m4p0h6h3b.... is a dynamically generated one by google on the fly based on your geographic location and is subjected to change often hence the random string .I'm curious as to so why you need that link to be accessible? You could just link your <audio> tag to `http://docs.google.com/uc?export=open&id=1Tnh8UgAzFKrp6e-8QCl21v16L3yVCqso` and would play just fine