# Get variable from code.gs(Google apps script) to html page(/url parameters)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a variable Serialnumber assigned in my code.gs and i want it my url parameter.

HTML:
Code.gsv:[click here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H1zJUWL4xbATSs2YZIVjbqeEWFxwEqbS/view?usp=share_link)

I've tried this way but in my success.html page it's showing undefined.
[image: like this]

note: my success.html page is client side(not added in apps script)

Answer (score 0):

If you share your code it will be easier to debug but in the meantime, to pass a variable from the server-side (Code.gs) to the client-side (HTML), you can use the google.script.run API to call a server-side function from the client-side and pass the variable as a parameter. Here's an example of how you can modify your code to pass the Serialnumber variable from the server-side to the client-side as a URL parameter:

Code.gs:

```
function doGet() {
  var Serialnumber = "12345";
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Page')
      .evaluate()
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)
      .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
      .setXRobotsTag(HtmlService.XRobotsTag.DOINDEX, HtmlService.XRobotsTag.FOLLOW)
      .setFaviconUrl("https://www.example.com/favicon.ico")
      .setTitle("Example")
      .addMetaTag('description', 'Example page')
      .addMetaTag('keywords', 'example')
      .setParam('Serialnumber', Serialnumber); // Pass Serialnumber as a parameter
}

function doGetWithParameter(Serialnumber) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Success')
      .evaluate()
      .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
      .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)
      .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
      .setXRobotsTag(HtmlService.XRobotsTag.DOINDEX, HtmlService.XRobotsTag.FOLLOW)
      .setFaviconUrl("https://www.example.com/favicon.ico")
      .setTitle("Success")
      .addMetaTag('description', 'Success page')
      .addMetaTag('keywords', 'success')
      .setParam('Serialnumber', Serialnumber); // Pass Serialnumber as a parameter
}

function processForm(form) {
  var Serialnumber = form.Serialnumber;
  google.script.run.doGetWithParameter(Serialnumber); // Call the doGetWithParameter function with Serialnumber as a parameter
}
```

Page.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <title>Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form onsubmit="event.preventDefault(); google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.page.update).processForm(this)">
      <label for="Serialnumber">Serial number:</label>
      <input type="text" id="Serialnumber" name="Serialnumber"><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Success.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <title>Success</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Serial number: <?= Serialnumber ?></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the above code, Serialnumber is passed from doGet function to Page.html as a parameter using the setParam method. When the form is submitted, the processForm function is called, which calls the doGetWithParameter function on the server-side with the Serialnumber parameter. The doGetWithParameter function returns the Success.html template, which displays the Serialnumber parameter using PHP-style  tags.

Comment: Hi @Hugo , thanks for your reply. I have added my code in link. Can please give solution accordingly